# Automatically insert newline where there are blank lines

Tags: spacing

Is it possible to have Latex automatically insert a `\newline` when it encounters a blank line of text?

I find putting `\newline`'s everywhere tends to make my text unreadable.

Comment: Use the `parskip` package.

Comment: Why are you putting in `\newline` at all? In any event a blank line starts a new paragraph.

Comment: you should almost never need `\newline` or `\\ ` in text in latex. End a paragraph with a blank line not with a command.

Comment: See also [When to use \par and when \\, \newline, or blank lines](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664)